# Getting password hashes and salts from Drupal 7

Tags: database, security, users

I need to get user accounts' password hashes and salts from a Drupal 7 app, so as to migrate these accounts into [Stormpath](http://docs.stormpath.com/rest/product-guide/#create-an-account-with-an-existing-password-hash). Could you please help me to figure out where this data is stored and how to get it from the DB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The password hashes & salts are stored in the `pass` column in the `users` table with the first 4 bytes being settings, the next 8 bytes being the salt, and the remaining the password. See the [`user_hash_password()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21password.inc/function/user_hash_password/7) &  [`_password_generate_salt()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21password.inc/function/_password_generate_salt/7) docs for how salts are generated.

Comment: Thanks. Where are the salt byte arrays stored though?

Comment: I think I found the answer in a comment on http://stackoverflow.com/a/9877006/805141 : "the salt is the 5th character through the 12th in the stored Drupal string." Presumably the string he's referring to is the hashed password.

Comment: Could you please confirm that this is correct @Shawn Conn ?

Comment: Correct. The first 4 bytes are settings, the next 8 (5-12) are the salt, the rest is the password hash. I've updated the answer to make that clearer.